# Apache Ignite CacheConfiguration repeat for each data set?

Tags: ignite

I am trying to modify default-config.xml by adding cacheConfiguration tags.  Do i need to repeat cacheConfiguration XML tag for each data set RDD that i am tyring to keep to keep it in the memory ?  Can i set backups to 0, if i don't want it.

ex:

> ```
>  <property name="cacheConfiguration">
>     <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
>         <property name="name" value="TEST1_RDD"/>
>         <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
>         <property name="backups" value="0"/>
>     </bean>
> </property> <property name="cacheConfiguration">
>     <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
>         <property name="name" value="TEST2_RDD"/>
>         <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
>         <property name="backups" value="0"/>
>     </bean>
> </property>
> ```

Also, do i need to specify explicitly write synchronization mode ?  and by default which one Ignite consider ?

ex:

> `<property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="FULL_SYNC"/>`

Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You have to write configuration for each cache as your cache may have different functionality/purpose and you have to set configuration according to it.

For **backups** it's default value is **0** and for **CacheWriteSynchronizationMode** default value is **PRIMARY_SYNC**

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to define cache templates, if you don't want to provide the same configuration for caches: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-template